# Detecting browsers installed so Process.Start("chrome") won't error

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm trying to let the user choose the browser my application uses to launch urls. Currently it uses the default browser, but some people want to specify a different browser.

I'd like to show only installed browsers in the list, and I'm launching them like this:

`Process.Start("chrome", url);`  [(more info)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0)

The problem is, if Chrome isn't installed (and in the path), it'll fail.

How can I check whether this call will fail, without calling it (so I can pre-filter my list, and remove chrome if it's not going to work)?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows all of the installed applications have a key in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` registry key. One solution would be to iterate over all the entries in this key and see if they match the names of your supported browsers.

Once you've got the registry keys for each browser, you can then get the `Path` value of each key, and see if the executable file exists in the specified path.

One thing to note is that on 64-bit versions of Windows, 32-bit apps are listed in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`.

Comment: This feels a little dirty, but I'm guessing it's the best way I'm going to find so I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Jared, I your solution used to work, but either because of Windows 8 or the newest Chrome version, the key is not in the registry anymore...

Comment: Found the new path for Chrome:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe

Comment: Regarding the Wow6432Node subkey that you mentioned: Do I have to determine which to check, or will it be inferred by Windows if it is a 32-bit computer?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap `Process.Start("chrome", url);` it in a `try/catch` (catching the exception thrown when browser is not installed)

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: The problem with this, is that it will launch the browsers if they exist. I need to filter the list without spawning browser.

Comment: D'oy! I haven't had my coffee yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this function in C# to detect if chrome is installed without launching browser window and without peeking into windows registry:

```
    bool checkChromeInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            string process = "chrome.exe";
            string args = "--no-startup-window --start-in-incognito";
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = process;
            psi.Arguments = args;
            var chrome_ps = Process.Start(psi);
            if (chrome_ps != null)
            {
                //chrome exists and started successully. exit chrome.
                chrome_ps.Kill();
            }
            //if reached this far, means chrome exist.
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //got an error, probably chrome is not installed(not sure however).
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The command line argument --no-startup-window starts chrome in background. Got the chrome switch from [this link](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

You can call above function like this:

```
    if (!checkChromeInstalled())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please install Google Chrome to run this app.\n\nIf chrome is already installed, make sure 'chrome.exe' is set in Path envirinment variable.");
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
```