# How to get Google Chrome & Firefox Installed Version on a system in Go lang

Tags: go

I want to check weather Google Chrome 18+ or Firefox 16+ is installed on system or not.?? Is there any way to do this in Google Go Lang on windows??

Comment: Probably you could read metadata from exe file - at least in chrome there is file version in it. No idea if there is something to read metadata from file in go. Should not be difficult to make though

Comment: @Uriel_SVK But anyway to find where exe is??

Comment: just check if file exists on default locations, or check registry - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425465/enumerating-registry-values-in-go-golang
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887677/detecting-browsers-installed-so-process-startchrome-wont-error

Comment: Here is another discussion for checking the registry using C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry. As we know there is no problem calling C/C++ libraries from Go :)

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Any Registry Entry for Google Chrome??

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Chrome ?